# Get URL Parameter in PHP using slash

Tags: php, url

Ill be using parameter of URL like this 
http://localhost/biyahero/user/mark instead of this http://localhost/biyahero/user.php?name=mark

I already tried

```
 $test=explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
echo $test[3];
```

And it works fine, but when im accessing the actual page, both css and js is not working properly.
what am I missing ?

Comment: just use absolute URLs for css and js.. instead of `../../path/to/cssFile.css` use `/path/to/cssFile.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use absolute URLs to load the css and js files.

Instead of relative URLs like:

```
../../path/to/cssFile.css
```

use absolute URLs:

```
/path/to/cssFile.css
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the server's PATH_INFO variable for this to work correctly. But be aware that you need to configure your server accordingly as well.

Then in PHP you can call [pathinfo()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) like this:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Server configuration for
Apache

```
# Set document root to be "webroot"
DocumentRoot "path/to/webroot"
<Directory "path/to/webroot">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

and Nginx:

```
server {
    # ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # ...
}
```

WARNING: this can pose several security issues if not configured properly, make sure that:

1. User upload files can never be accessed when this rule is applied
2. set `["cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini][2]`